# How do you make Windows executables executable from the Windows menu

Tags: windows-10

When I press the Windows button, I can type in programs to start them.
However some programs don't show up when I start typing. How do you make those programs appear, if I know where the executable is. Where do you have to put it?

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** Create a shortcut in the Start menu for the program you wish to appear in your search.

There are two criteria for the stuff that appear in your search:

- **Indexing Options**: If a file name is in the Windows search index, it will appear in your search results. Windows 10 version 1607 by default indexes the Start menu and Control Panel, so when you type the name of the shortcut in the Start menu or Control Panel, it appears in the search results. You can change indexing options though. Just search "Indexing Options"!
- **`PATH`environment variable**: If a file is placed in one of the folders listed in the `PATH` environment variable, it will appear in your search results **if you type its full name**. There is an exception: For executable files, you only need to type its base name. (`.exe` is not required.) So:

  - If you type `SmartScreenSettings`, it will appear because `SmartScreenSettings.exe` is stored in `C:\Windows\System32` and the latter is listed in the `PATH` environment variable.
  - If you type `Bubbles.scr`, it will appear because `Bubbles.scr` is stored in `C:\Windows\System32` and the latter is listed in the `PATH` environment variable.

  But of course, this second criterion is for superusers only. Ordinary people rarely remember full file names which are mostly gibberish, like `sdclt` or `rstrui`.